# CORS lets one ArcGIS JavaScript (REST) request through but not the other

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api

I have a problem with Cross-Origin-Requests invoked by the ArcGIS Javascript API.

I'm able to access my web app without any issues if I use `localhost:8080`. But a REST call (by the ArcGIS JS API) fails if I use `mymachine.local`.

The `exportImage` REST call works properly but the `query` REST call invoked by `featureLayer.selectFeatures` fails with a *Not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin* error.

I've gone through http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/09/29/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-with-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript/ but I don't think there's a problem with the CORS setup as one request goes through and the other one fails.

Answer (score 2):

Images are allowed in cross-domain requests, as are some other types of resource. You can read some of the limitations and reasons behind them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466737/why-the-cross-domain-ajax-is-a-security-concern)

Comment: Okay. Everything works fine in IE 9 as well as Firefox. Only chrome doesn't let the `query` request through.